# String character iteration Efficency in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was tasked with writing a string comparison function, where the result is as follows:

```
"ABC" & "abc" returns 0;
"abc" & "abcd" return -1;
"abcd" & "abc" returns 1;
```

My solution was:

```
function strcmp(a,b){
  var aTemp = a.toLowerCase();
  var bTemp = b.toLowerCase();
  if(aTemp === bTemp){
    return 0;
  } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < aTemp.length;i++){
        var charAtA = aTemp.charCodeAt(i), charAtB = bTemp.charCodeAt(i);
      if(charAtB !== charAtB) // NaN returns false when compared to itself.
        return 1;
      if(charAtA < charAtB)
                return -1;
       else if(charAtA > charAtB)
        return 1;
    }
    if(bTemp.length > aTemp.length)
        return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

When presenting my solution (besides finding a bug in the code), I was asked why I had converted the strings to lowercase and stored them in a parameter, rather than for each iteration of the for loop, converting the character to lowercase.
So my question is, what is the right way to convert a string to lowercase, what is more efficient, or was the person that I submitted the answer to just playing mind games with me?

Comment: what would be the output of `"abc" & "abd"`?

Comment: Seems overcomplicated? -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1w7kudsj/**

Comment: @adeneo Your fiddle returns 1 for `strcmp("fooABC", "oabc")`

Comment: @Barmar - it could return 666 for all I care, it's written for the three examples posted, there's no other explanation of what the function is supposed to do, but if it's only suppose to compare the start of the string, or do so case-sensitive, that result is clearly not correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the whole string to lowercase means you have to loop over all the characters, even though the comparison will stop at the first character difference. So if you convert each character as you get to it, you only do as many conversions as you need to get the result. Unless the two strings are equal, you'll always do fewer conversions this way; when they're equal, you do the same number of conversions.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question, it is correct that you saved the lowercase string into a variable. If you would have converted inside the for loop, then on every iteration the `toLowerCase()` method would have been called called, which is inefficient.

Now, not sure if you know, but javascript has a method similar to strcmp, called `localeCompare()`. So an alternative to your code would be this:

```
a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
```